# vspace*{1in} + geometry with 1in margin = 2-5/32" margin

Tags: geometry, units

For the first page in my document (book class) I need to set the title 2" from the top margin.

Using Overleaf with XeLaTeX, the following MWE produces output that is 2-5/32" from the top edge of the paper. All other margins are correct.

What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10,paper=letter,usegeometry=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe=true]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{1in}
\fbox{\textbf{The top of this box should be at 2" from top of page.}}
\end{document}
```

For the moment, I've just specified a new top margin for the page as follows, which works as expected.

I would really like to understand what is going on with the other method though.

```
\newgeometry{hmargin=1in,tmargin=2in,bmargin=1in}
...
\restoregeometry
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How did you measure the 2-5/32 inch (I assume with this notation you mean 1.84375 inch)? Did you print it out and measure it with a ruler?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and your response.

2 and 5/32 inches (2.156). I printed it and measured with a ruler. Note that the side and top margins measure correctly, so I don't think it's related to a printer issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier if you use a rule instead of a \vspace as you don't have to calculate how topskip and the baselineskip matters. The tikz picture is only there to show the distances.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10,paper=letter,usegeometry=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr 1in}\fbox{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[red,<->](current page.north)--++(0,-2in)--++(-2cm,0);%
  \textbf{The top of this box should be at 2" from top of page.}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful.

Out of curiosity, what is the dimension from the baseline to the top of the fbox? Is it 10pts (the font size) or is it \baselineskip, or something else entirely?